# vowel and consonant grouping (without regex)

Tags: javascript, string

```
console.log(recompose("KiKdaola"));
```

So I have this code and the result I'm trying to yield from the function 'recompose' is this

```
-->[ 'K', 'i', 'Kd', 'ao', 'l', 'a' ]
```

Couldn't  achieve this clustering/grouping vowels and consonants without regex any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us any of your attempts at least?

Comment: Use a loop and check if previous and current item are of same *type*

Comment: `without regex' - why's that? Actually using split with capturing groups seems to be the most direct approach.

Comment: @raina77ow probably an additional requirement in a homework context, so as to not make it _too_ easy :-)

Comment: actually a coding challenge I'm trying to solve, not even the complete problem just a small part of it(actually the crux of it but whatever). could achieve it with regex but tryna solve it without regex so decided to ask it.

Comment: Please show some attempts of yours and don't leave this as a "solve this for me" kind of question. Try to ask something more specific ("I've tried *this*, but the problem with this approach is *that*, is there a workaround?").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can split your string then process it with a flipping flag:

```js
const str = "KiKdaola";

const VOWELS = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

function isVowel(ch) {
  const lch = ch.toLowerCase();
  return VOWELS.includes(lch);
}

function recompose(str) {
  let prevIsVowel;
  return str.split('').reduce((acc, ch) => {
    const currIsVowel = isVowel(ch);
    if (prevIsVowel !== currIsVowel) {
      acc.push(''); 
    }
    prevIsVowel = currIsVowel;
    acc[acc.length - 1] += ch;
    return acc;
  }, []);
}

console.log(recompose(str));
```

Yet, for the sake of completeness here's the regex-based way - using String.split() with capturing groups:

```js
const str = 'abceefdfdei';

const results = str.split(/([aeiou]+)/i).filter(Boolean);

console.log(results);
```